# Why my app stops downloading always the same file at 5-10% of progress? (Only on a few machines)

Tags: java, download, launcher

My app seems to work on most of the machines, but some just don't want to cooperate... The files on the server are fine, server itself isn't down or anything. The problem is that the app downloads all required files (up to 600KB) correctly except one (12MB). I can't figure out what is wrong. My guess is that there's something running in background that blocks the downloading thread of my app, or maybe the router blocks some of the packets? All I can see is that progress bar goes up to 4% (sometimes even up to 8!) and then stops with no errors or exceptions, while all the other downloads go up to 100% without problems. Any ideas?

Here's the class I use to download files (I've downloaded the whole 'download manager' script from http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/javax.swing/how-to-create-a-download-manager-in-java.html):

```
class Download extends Observable implements Runnable {
  private static final int MAX_BUFFER_SIZE = 1024;

  public static final String STATUSES[] = { "Pobieranie", "Pauza", "OK", "Anulowany",
      "Błąd" };

  public static final int DOWNLOADING = 0;

  public static final int PAUSED = 1;

  public static final int COMPLETE = 2;

  public static final int CANCELLED = 3;

  public static final int ERROR = 4;

  private URL url; // download URL

  private int size; // size of download in bytes

  private int downloaded; // number of bytes downloaded

  private int status; // current status of download

  // Constructor for Download.
  public Download(URL url) {
    this.url = url;
    size = -1;
    downloaded = 0;
    status = DOWNLOADING;
    System.err.println("==========Pobieram plik: " + url.toString());

    // Begin the download.
    download();
  }

  // Get this download's URL.
  public String getUrl() {
    //return url.toString();
      return getFileName(url);
  }

  // Get this download's size.
  public int getSize() {
    return size;
  }

  // Get this download's progress.
  public float getProgress() {
    return ((float) downloaded / size) * 100;
  }

  public int getStatus() {
    return status;
  }

  public void pause() {
    status = PAUSED;
    stateChanged();
  }

  public void resume() {
    status = DOWNLOADING;
    stateChanged();
    download();
  }

  public void cancel() {
    status = CANCELLED;
    stateChanged();
  }

  private void error() {
    status = ERROR;
    stateChanged();
  }

  private void download() {
    Thread thread = new Thread(this);
    thread.start();
  }

  // Get file name portion of URL.
  private String getFileName(URL url) {
    String fileName = url.getFile();
    return fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
  }

  // Download file.
  public void run() {
    RandomAccessFile file = null;
    InputStream stream = null;

    try {
      // Open connection to URL.
      HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

      // Specify what portion of file to download.
      connection.setRequestProperty("Range", "bytes=" + downloaded + "-");

      // Connect to server.
      connection.connect();

      // Make sure response code is in the 200 range.
      if (connection.getResponseCode() / 100 != 2) {
        error();
      }

      // Check for valid content length.
      int contentLength = connection.getContentLength();
      if (contentLength < 1) {
        error();
      }

      /*
       * Set the size for this download if it hasn't been already set.
       */
      if (size == -1) {
        size = contentLength;
        stateChanged();
      }

      File f = new File(Files.download_dir + Files.SEPARATOR + getFileName(url));
      if (f.exists()) f.delete();
      // Open file and seek to the end of it.
      file = new RandomAccessFile(Files.download_dir + Files.SEPARATOR + getFileName(url), "rw");
      file.seek(downloaded);

      stream = connection.getInputStream();
      while (status == DOWNLOADING) {
        /*
         * Size buffer according to how much of the file is left to download.
         */
        byte buffer[];
        if (size - downloaded > MAX_BUFFER_SIZE) {
          buffer = new byte[MAX_BUFFER_SIZE];
        } else {
          buffer = new byte[size - downloaded];
        }

        // Read from server into buffer.
        int read = stream.read(buffer);
        if (read == -1)
          break;

        // Write buffer to file.
        file.write(buffer, 0, read);
        downloaded += read;
        //System.out.println("Pobralem juz: " + String.valueOf(downloaded));
        stateChanged();
      }

      /*
       * Change status to complete if this point was reached because downloading
       * has finished.
       */
      if (status == DOWNLOADING) {
        status = COMPLETE;
        stateChanged();
      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
      error();
    } finally {
      // Close file.
      if (file != null) {
        try {
          file.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
      }

      // Close connection to server.
      if (stream != null) {
        try {
          stream.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
      }
    }
  }

  private void stateChanged() {
    setChanged();
    notifyObservers();
  }
}
```

(If you need more code, just let me know and I'll upload everything somewhere.)

Comment: It would probably be that you need to flush the data to the disk

Comment: What makes you certain that it is your code that is the problem? Can you download that file via web browser? Virus checkers or content filters sometimes choke on large files if they're not properly configured, or just plain suck. At my last work place there were several cases where I had to get IT to download a jar file for me because the antivirus service they used couldn't handle it. Given that you say your code works on "most of the machines", I'd look at the machines not the code.

Comment: Yes, they can download the file via web browser and there are no errors. I tried to help them via TeamViewer (remote desktop app) - I disabled their anti-virus and firewall programs, checked everything, but still no results. What is weird, I ran my app with admin rights on one of the machines and it worked. Sadly, the others still had the same problem. What else could be the reason?

@Cole Johnson: What do you mean by "to flush the data to the disk"?

Comment: I mean that data is actually buffered and you need to push it to the disk before retrieving any more.

Comment: I believe that "file.write(buffer, 0, read);" does exactly what you are talking about.